# Unable to run python script from command line using ./<scriptname>

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tried searching many posts but unable to find the answer.

I have a simple python script (test.py) written as:

## !/usr/bin/env python (tried with #!/usr/bin/python)

print("Hellow World")

but when I am trying to run this script from command line (from the script location) as ./test.py, it is always giving error
"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

"which python" is giving me below path:

## !/cygdrive/c/Users/User>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python

I am able to run the script using "python test.py" but unable to understand the issue with "./"

Comment: You still need to follow your shell's conventions when running software.

Comment: You have cygwin, could try ./test.py in cygwin terminal.

Comment: In cygwin terminal it is working with ./test.py but can I run directly in windows with ./test.py as I have provided the interpreter using shebang. I had seen many posts saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are running on Windows and trying to use semantics from a POSIX-like shell.

Instead of running `./tesy.py` try `start test.py`

Comment: This worked and it opens a new window to run the script. But is it wrong to run ./test.py as in many posts I have seen people are asking to run like this.

Comment: Windows Command prompt / Batch does not understand what a `.` is on its own. the dot is a special character in POSIX /  UNIX-like environments. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)) for more info. The posts you mention were probably made by people on Linux / BSD / mac, etc

Comment: Well, no, you *could* do `.\script.py`...but no one does.